# Quartz Scheduler: inconsistent times of trigger execution

Tags: java, spring, triggers, weblogic, quartz-scheduler

I have a couple of Java applications that utilise Quartz 1.6.6 upon Weblogic with Spring (one uses Spring v. 2.5.4; the other uses Spring v. 3.1.1). My architecture has two application servers in the Weblogic cluster.

Both applications have simple triggers set up (using `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean`, `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean` and `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean`). They are all set to run every 60 seconds.

I have added logging to the associated `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean` (at the start of the `executeInternal()` method) which writes the time of when the process gets executed.

What I have found is that the time is inconsistent - sometimes the execution for a given minute will not happen. Examples:

Application 1 has one trigger process which was executed at the following times:

```
14:26:26,098
14:28:26,089
14:31:26,096
14:33:26,093
14:35:26,095
14:36:26,098
14:38:26,103
```

Application 2 has two trigger processes which were executed at the following times:

```
14:40:05,951 (trigger 1)
14:41:05,951 (trigger 2)
14:42:05,943 (trigger 1)
14:43:05,954 (trigger 2)
14:44:05,937 (trigger 1)
14:45:05,956 (trigger 2)
14:46:05,953 (trigger 2)
14:47:05,937 (trigger 1)
14:48:05,941 (trigger 1)
14:49:05,939 (trigger 1)
14:50:05,951 (trigger 2)
```

If I switch one Weblogic application server off, then both applications quite happily run all their jobs each and every minute.

I have checked the database tables for all the jobs and `QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS.REPEAT_INTERVAL` is correct (60,000 milliseconds). The difference between `QRTZ_TRIGGERS.PREV_FIRE_TIME` and `QRTZ_TRIGGERS.NEXT_FIRE_TIME` is also 60,000.

My `quartzProperties` definition in the application context file has the following entries:

```
<property name="quartzProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">MyClusteredScheduler</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">5</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">5000</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource">myDS</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL">{db connection string}</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user">{username}</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password">{password}</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections">5</prop>
        <prop key="org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery">select 0 from dual</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

Any thoughts upon why this should be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: any chance you can check whether there are any unreleased locks on the database when you run the two sets of schedulers?

Comment: Do your jobs finish off in 1 minute? Because quartz jobs are stateful, and hence won't have 2 parallel job instatances. Also, consider increasing the thread count.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.

1) Not sure as to what I would check the database; I can confirm that QRTZ_TRIGGERS.TRIGGER_STATE is mainly WAITING with a few seconds of ACQUIRED every minute.
2) Yes, the jobs finish well within the 60 second time period.
3) Will increase the thread count and report back.

Comment: Have increased org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount to 50 and redeployed, but it made no difference - there are still inconsistent running times. One thing I have noticed is that the database tables are being updated every minute as if the job is running each 60 seconds but I'm not seeing the logs being updated (logged from the QuartzJobBean's executeInternal() method).

Comment: Can you try after setting isclustered value to false .i guess specifying it as clustered makes the quartz jobs to share th run time/load

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do. I have attempted to include clustering because I was finding that with the Weblogic architecture we have, triggers were being fired twice, once by each application server. I was hoping to get clustering implemented so that the two application servers would synchronise and each trigger would get fired once.

Comment: I have upgraded to Quartz version 1.8.6 (any version of Quartz beyond version 2.0 won't work with Spring, apparently) and an experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Have tried setting the isClustered value to "false". When I try and deploy the application, I get an error stating that the primary key index on table QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS has been violated. This is presumably because each application server is trying to add its own version of the job to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemingly fixed: the issue was more to do with the reliance on inconsistent logging messages to suggest inconsistent trigger times than anything to do with Quartz.